# How to do string comparison properly in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am executing my url through shell script and storing the response in a variable.

```
http://hostname.domain.com:8080/beat
```

After hitting the above url, I will be getting the below response which I need to parse it and extract value of `state` from it

```
num_retries_allowed: 3 count: 30 count_behind: 100 state: POST_INIT num_rounds: 60 hour_col: 2 day_col: 0
```

Now I am extracting value of state variable from the above string using grep.

```
#send the request, put response in variable
DATA=$(wget -O - -q -t 1 http://hostname.domain.com:8080/beat)

#grep $DATA for state
state=$(grep -oP 'state: \K\S+' <<< "$DATA")
[[ -z "$state" ]] && state=0

echo $state
```

Also if in `$DATA` variable `state:` string is not there by any chance, then I want to assign `0` to `state` variable. After that I want to verify the conditionals and exit out of the script depending on that.

If `state` is equal to `POST_INIT` then exit successfully out of the shell script or if `state` is equal to `0`, then exit successfully as well.

```
if [[ $state -eq "POST_INIT" || $state -eq "0" ]]; then exit 0; fi
```

So my above if condition is not working somehow. Since what I have noticed is if my `state` variable value is `IN_INIT`, then also it is exiting out of the shell script? Is there anything wrong I am doing here in the string comparison?

Comment: `-eq` is for numbers. Use `=` for strings.

Comment: POSIX says `=`. but bash accepts `==` if you want to use that instead (though I don't recommend it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-eq` is for comparing numbers. `=` is for comparing strings.

If you were using `[` instead of `[[` you would be getting an error for a value of `POST_INIT` and `IN_INIT`.

```
$ state=POST_INIT
$ [ $state -eq 0 ]
-bash: [: POST_INIT: integer expression expected
$ echo $?
2
```

What I believe `[[` is doing is actually being more clever and more annoying.

I believe it is expanding the variable and then using the expanded value in an arithmetic context (in which variables are expanded even from bare words) and since the variable `POST_INIT` doesn't have a value that gets expanded to `0` by default and your check passes.

```
$ state=POST_INIT
$ [[ $state -eq 0 ]]; echo $?
0
$ POST_INIT=5
$ [[ $state -eq 0 ]]; echo $?
1
$ POST_INIT=0
$ [[ $state -eq 0 ]]; echo $?
0
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. I tested this `if [[ "$state" == "POST_INIT" || "$state" == "0" ]]; then exit 0; fi` and it works fine. Do you see any issues using this?

Comment: I think that looks fine. For a one-liner you might choose to use `[[ "$state" == "POST_INIT" || "$state" == "0" ]] && exit 0` instead to reduce clutter a bit but that's stylistic and not meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

trying this

```
 if [[ "$state" == "POST_INIT" || "$state" == "0" ]];
```

will help because if you use something like [ $state == "POST_INIT" ] , it ignores $state if it is null and would rather read the statement as [ == "POST_INIT". including " " ,prevents that case.

Comment: Yet when `[[` and `]]` is used, you don't need to quote the variable.  `if [[ $state == "POST_INIT" ... ` will work.   They are automatically quoted, and it works for both multi-word and empty  string case.